# Scrollbar "dragger" size not changing when maximum value set

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

Should the "dragger" on a scroll bar be increasing as I set the `.MaximumValue` property of the scroll bar to a smaller value?

I am using a wpf scroll bar.

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Xaml:

```
<ScrollBar Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="scrollBar1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="18" Scroll="scrollBar1_Scroll" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="5" />
```

Code to set maxvalue:

```
scrollBarMaximum = numberOfRecords - numberOfRecordsToLoad;
```

Comment: It depends on your template.  Have you customized the template?

Comment: Nope not at all. I thought it would do it automatically? IE if the maximumvalue property is set to 10 the icon would take up 1/10th of the scroll bar.